# how can i exit the program without it returning a value?

Tags: c, if-statement, numbers, return, exit

output is 0 when entered 1001 or something greater than it.

it should give 0 when the number isn't abundant and should exit if entered number is greater than the limit ,have tried using goto exit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int i, sum = 0;
    if (1 <= n <= 1000)
    {
        for (i = 2; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
                sum = sum + i;
        }
        (sum > n) ? printf("1") : printf("0");
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

Comment: If you write some function `void myFunction()` in one file and you declare a function `extern int myFunction()` in another file, you can call `x = myFunction()` in the other file but some "random" value will be returned (and written to `x`). The same is true if you write `void main()` instead of `int main()`: The file that calls `main()` will not "return without exit code", but it will see a "random" value returned by `main()` and pass that value to `exit()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in this if statement

```
if (1 <= n <= 1000)
```

is equivalent to

```
if ( ( 1 <= n ) <= 1000)
```

the result of the sub-expression `1 <= n`  is either `0` or `1`. So this value is in any case less than `1000`.

From the C Standard (6.5.8 Relational operators)

> 6 Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than
> or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the
> specified relation is true and 0 if it is false. The result has type
> int.

You need to write

```
if (1 <= n && n <= 1000)
```

using the logical AND operator.

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```